# Problem with authentication using WebDAV - davfs2

Tags: linux, webdav

This is my first contact with WebDAV and I have slight problems connecting to end-point.

1. Credentials are working fine when using Cyberduck client.
2. I need to configure container with **davfs2** on Alpine or Ubuntu.
3. I don't have access to WebDAV server (SaaS E-Commerce platform, https://shoper.pl)
4. Using **davfs2** I have managed to mount Nextcloud WebDAV (demo account) with success and no issues at all.

**Versions:** davfs2/1.5.5 neon/0.30.2

Details are below. Any suggestions?

Error:

```
Could not authenticate to server: rejected Digest challenge, rejected Basic challenge
```

/var/log/syslog

```
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Identity match for 'devshop-******.shoparena.pl': good
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Request sent; retry is 0.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [status-line] < HTTP/1.1 200 OK#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2020 12:33:28 GMT#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [date], Value: [Sat, 25 Jan 2020 12:33:28 GMT]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [content-type], Value: [text/html; charset=UTF-8]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Transfer-Encoding: chunked#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [transfer-encoding], Value: [chunked]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Connection: keep-alive#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [connection], Value: [keep-alive]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Keep-Alive: timeout=20#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [keep-alive], Value: [timeout=20]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Dav: 1#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [dav], Value: [1]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Ms-Author-Via: DAV#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [ms-author-via], Value: [DAV]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Accept-Ranges: bytes#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [accept-ranges], Value: [bytes]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Vary: Brief,Prefer#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [vary], Value: [Brief,Prefer]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Allows: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MOVE, COPY#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [allows], Value: [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MOVE, COPY]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Cache-Namespace: 148#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-cache-namespace], Value: [148]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-XSS-Protection: 1#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-xss-protection], Value: [1]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Powered-By: DCSaaS#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-powered-by], Value: [DCSaaS]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Server: DCSaaS/httpd#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [server], Value: [DCSaaS/httpd]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-content-type-options], Value: [nosniff]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Set-Cookie: fp=4220404054; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [set-cookie], Value: [fp=4220404054; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] #015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: End of headers.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running post_headers hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [chunk] < 0#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Got chunk size: 0
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] #015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: End of headers.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running post_send hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: ah_post_send (#0), code is 200 (want 401), WWW-Authenticate is (none)
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Request ends, status 200 class 2xx, error line:#012200 OK
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running destroy hooks.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Request ends.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: ah_create, for WWW-Authenticate
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running pre_send hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Sending request headers:#012PROPFIND /webapi/webdav/ HTTP/1.1#015#012User-Agent: davfs2/1.5.5 neon/0.30.2#015#012Connection: TE#015#012TE: trailers#015#012Host: devshop-******.shoparena.pl#015#012Depth: 1#015#012Content-Length: 257#015#012Content-Type: application/xml#015#012#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Sending request-line and headers:
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Sending request body:
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Body block (257 bytes):#012[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>#012<propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop>#012<resourcetype xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<getcontentlength xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<getetag xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<getlastmodified xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<executable xmlns="http://apache.org/dav/props/"/>#012</prop></propfind>#012]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Request sent; retry is 1.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [status-line] < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2020 12:33:28 GMT#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [date], Value: [Sat, 25 Jan 2020 12:33:28 GMT]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [content-type], Value: [text/html; charset=UTF-8]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Transfer-Encoding: chunked#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [transfer-encoding], Value: [chunked]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Connection: keep-alive#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [connection], Value: [keep-alive]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Keep-Alive: timeout=20#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [keep-alive], Value: [timeout=20]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6"#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [www-authenticate], Value: [Basic realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6"]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Www-Authenticate: Digest realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6", domain="devshop-******.shoparena.pl", nonce="c66bd42f37c902e4c2cd14d532d285a1", opaque="d75db7b160fe72d1346d2bd1f67bfd10", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [www-authenticate], Value: [Digest realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6", domain="devshop-******.shoparena.pl", nonce="c66bd42f37c902e4c2cd14d532d285a1", opaque="d75db7b160fe72d1346d2bd1f67bfd10", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Dav: 1#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [dav], Value: [1]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Cache-Namespace: 148#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-cache-namespace], Value: [148]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-XSS-Protection: 1#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-xss-protection], Value: [1]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Powered-By: DCSaaS#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-powered-by], Value: [DCSaaS]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Server: DCSaaS/httpd#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [server], Value: [DCSaaS/httpd]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-content-type-options], Value: [nosniff]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Set-Cookie: fp=1065983822; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [set-cookie], Value: [fp=1065983822; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] #015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: End of headers.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running post_headers hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [chunk] < 0#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Got chunk size: 0
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] #015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: End of headers.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running post_send hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: ah_post_send (#0), code is 401 (want 401), WWW-Authenticate is Basic realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6", Digest realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6", domain="devshop-******.shoparena.pl", nonce="c66bd42f37c902e4c2cd14d532d285a1", opaque="d75db7b160fe72d1346d2bd1f67bfd10", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Got challenge (code 401).
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Got 'Basic' challenge.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Got 'Digest' challenge.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Trying Digest challenge...
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Using domain /devshop-******.shoparena.pl from devshop-******.shoparena.pl
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Got qop, using 2617-style.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: H(A1) is [f4191e958585d980c418e87b51ebccfe]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Accepting digest challenge.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Accepted Digest challenge.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running pre_send hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: Sending 'Digest' response.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: auth: '/webapi/webdav/' is inside auth domain: 0.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Sending request headers:#012PROPFIND /webapi/webdav/ HTTP/1.1#015#012User-Agent: davfs2/1.5.5 neon/0.30.2#015#012Connection: TE#015#012TE: trailers#015#012Host: devshop-******.shoparena.pl#015#012Depth: 1#015#012Content-Length: 257#015#012Content-Type: application/xml#015#012#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Sending request-line and headers:
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Sending request body:
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Body block (257 bytes):#012[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>#012<propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop>#012<resourcetype xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<getcontentlength xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<getetag xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<getlastmodified xmlns="DAV:"/>#012<executable xmlns="http://apache.org/dav/props/"/>#012</prop></propfind>#012]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Request sent; retry is 1.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [status-line] < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2020 12:33:29 GMT#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [date], Value: [Sat, 25 Jan 2020 12:33:29 GMT]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [content-type], Value: [text/html; charset=UTF-8]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Transfer-Encoding: chunked#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [transfer-encoding], Value: [chunked]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Connection: keep-alive#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [connection], Value: [keep-alive]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Keep-Alive: timeout=20#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [keep-alive], Value: [timeout=20]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6"#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [www-authenticate], Value: [Basic realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6"]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Www-Authenticate: Digest realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6", domain="devshop-******.shoparena.pl", nonce="c66bd42f37c902e4c2cd14d532d285a1", opaque="d75db7b160fe72d1346d2bd1f67bfd10", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [www-authenticate], Value: [Digest realm="WebDAV Server 6.6.6", domain="devshop-******.shoparena.pl", nonce="c66bd42f37c902e4c2cd14d532d285a1", opaque="d75db7b160fe72d1346d2bd1f67bfd10", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Dav: 1#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [dav], Value: [1]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Cache-Namespace: 148#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-cache-namespace], Value: [148]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-XSS-Protection: 1#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-xss-protection], Value: [1]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Powered-By: DCSaaS#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-powered-by], Value: [DCSaaS]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Server: DCSaaS/httpd#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [server], Value: [DCSaaS/httpd]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [x-content-type-options], Value: [nosniff]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] Set-Cookie: fp=1381817215; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Header Name: [set-cookie], Value: [fp=1381817215; Path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000]
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] #015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: End of headers.
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Running post_headers hooks
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [chunk] < 0#015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: Got chunk size: 0
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: [hdr] #015
Jan 25 12:33:28 ubuntu-dev mount.davfs: End of headers.
```

**davfs2.conf**

```
      dav_user        root
      dav_group       root
      kernel_fs       fuse
      buf_size        32
      connect_timeout 30
      read_timeout    30
      retry           10
      max_retry       300
      dir_refresh     30
      file_refresh    10
      use_locks       0
      follow_redirect 1

debug config 
debug kernel 
debug cache
debug http 
debug xml 
debug httpauth 
debug locks
debug ssl 
debug httpbody 
debug most
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with how service owner was handling requests (he made his own modifications to WebDAV server).